# Using Dynamic Linq to set column name

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamic-linq

I have a database that is a little inverted. For every project row, there are columns for different Engineers involved. (architect engineer, construction engineer, mechanical engineer). I need to get a list of projects that are assigned to one person. So to do that, I need to write a query that will search for their job title in the columns based on a drop down list. I am using Dynamic Linq and I have written a query like this

```
Dim db As New DesignConstructionDataContext
Dim query = db.all_drawings.Where("@0 = Kevin O'lausen", "ddlJobTitle.value").Select("ProjectNumber").toList
```

But when I run this, the eror I get says "=" is not compatible with string values. and when I try using "is" instead, it says it needs to be a boolean value. I am very green to this Dynamic linq thing, any help would be great!

Comment: what field you want check?

Answer (score 0):

Methiks you a bit confused with linq.
So, as i understand

1. you have field name in `ddlJobTitle.value`, and
2. try check this field with value `"Kevin O'lausen"`

So you need change your query like

```
Dim query = db.all_drawings.Where(ddlJobTitle.value + " = @0", "Kevin O'lausen").Select("ProjectNumber").toList
```